# Is there a thread lock for QSqlQuery when using memory sqlite database

Tags: multithreading, qt, sqlite, thread-safety, in-memory-database

When I use several `QSqlQuery` querying and inserting in different table of the same memory `sqlite` database, it seems that there's a thread-safe lock so I cannot speed up my program.

I use `Windows API` `SetThreadAffinityMask` to make sure different thread working on different CPU thread. But I found the CPU using percent is never above 40%.(in my case,there's 4 `QSqlQuery` threads working on my PC which has 4 CPU thread)

If there's a lock, how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is will point you in the right direction?

[SQLite thread safety](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)

[SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6)

Comment: I know I can use it in pure `sqlite`, but right now I`m using `Qt`. In `sqlite` memory database doesn't have any thread lock. I'm not sure whether there's a lock in Qt regardless of the memory database.